# Sum of even-numbered items in Seq

Tags: scala

I'm trying to sum up even numbered items, and I went for making tuples and summing the first values in them, but It's creating a lot of objects which are immediately discarded.

Maybe someone can suggest more lightweight solution (maybe with `fold`)?

Edit: I meant numbers on even-numbered **positions**

Testcase:

```
List(1,3,1,3).foldLeft(x)(magic) === 2
```

Comment: Perhaps you could show your original solution so that people know what they are trying to improve upon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`zipWithIndex` can be used to zip `List(1,3,1,3)` with an index and return a `List` of tuples that can be filtered for even indices, mapped to get the the value, and then summed.

```
scala> List(1,3,1,3).zipWithIndex 
res0: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,0),(3,1), (1,2), (3,3))

List(1,3,1,3).zipWithIndex.filter(_._2 % 2 == 0).map(_._1).sum
res1: Int = 2
```

Comment: `filter` followed by `map` can be done together with `collect`. So in this case you can write: `List(1,3,1,3).zipWithIndex.collect{ case (i,idx) if idx % 2 == 0 => i}.sum`

Answer (score 4):

```
val ls = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
ls.filter(_ % 2 == 0).sum
```

**Edit:** position based:

```
ls.indices.filter(_ % 2 == 0).map(ls(_)).sum
```

Answer (score 3):

The other solutions have explicitly used the indices of the elements.

Another way to do it, would be to group into sub-lists of length 2, and take the first element of each:

```
scala> List(1, 3, 1, 3).grouped(2).map(_.head).sum
res0: Int = 2
```

(`head` should be safe to use, because `grouped` should not return empty lists.)

Comment: My original solution - all correct solution create intermediate tuples either way.

Comment: Oh, ok. You said your solution involved "tuples". This does not. But it does create 2-element lists, maybe that is what you meant.

Comment: `head` should never be used, I'd argue - http://stackoverflow.com/a/23184020/409976

Answer (score 2):

```
List(1,3,1,3).zipWithIndex.foldLeft(0) { (res, t) =>
  if (t._2%2 == 0)
    t._1 + res
  else
    res
}
```

`zipWithIndex` creates for each element in the list a tuple of the element and its index in the list and then you just have to fold and depending on the index either return the result or the result + the current item.

Answer (score 2):

The List.sliding function is pretty handy here:

```
List(1,2,3,4).drop(1).sliding(1,2).flatten.sum
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val ls = List(1,2,3,4,5)
ls.foldLeft(0)((sum,elem) => if(elem%2==0) sum+elem else sum)
```

There are multiple ways of doing it say by using `collect` or `map`, but they all will construct an internal list. For ex:

```
ls.collect{
  case n:Int if(n%2==0) => n
  case n:Int => 0
}.sum
```

`foldLeft` should be the fastest.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm.  It sounds like performance is a concern here, so I'd skip the zips and folds and go with a tail-recursive solution:

```
def f( nums:List[Int] ) = {
  def loop( nums:List[Int], soFar:Int ):Int = nums match {
    case x::_::rest => loop( rest, soFar+x )
    case    x::rest => soFar + x
    case          _ => soFar
  }
  loop(nums,0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To sum the even-numbered elements of a list without creating an intermediate list first (for performance and memory efficiency), you can do this:

```
val x = List(1, 11, 2, 22, 3, 33)
val result = x.foldLeft((0,0))((p,e) => if ((p._1)%2==0) (p._1+1, p._2) else (p._1+1, p._2+e))._2
//> result : Int = 66
```

"p" is a Tuple2[Int, Int] where the first element is the position index and the second element is the cumulative sum.  if the position index is even, it returns a new tuple with the next index and accumulating "e".  If the position index is odd, it returns a new tuple with the next index but without accumulating "e".

To sum the odd-numbered elements of the list, do the following:

```
val x = List(1, 11, 2, 22, 3, 33)
val result = x.foldLeft((0,0))((p,e) => if ((p._1)%2==0) (p._1+1, p._2+e) else (p._1+1, p._2))._2
//> result : Int = 6
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to above solutions you can use

```
List(1,2,3,4,5).zipWithIndex.filter(_._2 % 2 == 0).foldLeft(0)( (sum,ele) => {sum+ele._1} );

res6: Int = 9
```

Answer (score 0):

`List(1,3,1,3).foldLeft(0)((a, b)=> if(Math.abs(b%2) == 1)a+b else a)`