# Unable to Compare Long's in max Function

Tags: scala

I'm writing a `max` function in Scala:

```
scala> def max[Long](xs: List[Long]): Long = 
        xs.foldLeft(Long.MinValue){ (acc, elem) => if(elem > acc) elem else acc}
```

But it's giving me these compile-time errors. Looking at the Long [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.Long%24), this object clearly has the `MinValue` method. Also, `Long`'s can, of course,  be compared to each other.

```
<console>:7: error: value > is not a member of type parameter Long
       def max[Long](xs: List[Long]): Long = 
         xs.foldLeft(Long.MinValue){ (acc, elem) => if(elem > acc) elem else acc}

<console>:7: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Long(in method max)
 required: scala.Long
       def max[Long](xs: List[Long]): Long = 
          xs.foldLeft(Long.MinValue){ (acc, elem) => if(elem > acc) elem else acc}

<console>:7: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.Long
 required: Long(in method max)
       def max[Long](xs: List[Long]): Long = 
         xs.foldLeft(Long.MinValue){ (acc, elem) => if(elem > acc) elem else acc}
                                                                   ^
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Lose the type parameter `[Long]` and you're good.

Comment: Do you really want to return `Long.MinValue` if the list is empty? Maybe you should return `Option[Long]` instead?

Comment: @Lee You read my mind - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23183935/foldl-implementation-with-runtime-errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method is not generic so you don't need the type parameter:

```
def max(xs: List[Long]): Long = 
        xs.foldLeft(Long.MinValue){ (acc, elem) => if(elem > acc) elem else acc}
```

The generic parameter name `Long` is shadowing the `scala.Long` type you indend for the list and return type, so your signature is the same as:

```
def max[A](xs: List[A]): A
```

note you can also use the `max` method:

```
def max(xs: List[Long]): Long = xs.foldLeft(Long.MinValue){(acc, elem) => acc.max(elem)}
```

Comment: thanks, that worked. Why, though, does adding the `type parameter` cause the given compile-time errors?

Comment: Because then you are introducing a type parameter named `Long` which shadows the standard `Long` type. Basically it is as if you had said `def max[T](xs: List[T]): T`. And `T` being entirely unknown, there is no way to know if there is a `<` method that is applicable for it  (and you get type mismatchs when trying to pass instances of `T` where a `Long` is expected).