# Idiomatic scala for getting a single option out of two Options and throwing exception if two are available

Tags: scala, monads, scala-option

```
val one: Option[Int] = None    
val two = Some(2)

Option(one.getOrElse(two.getOrElse(null))) // Gives me Some(2) which I want

val one = Some(1)
val two = None

Option(one.getOrElse(two.getOrElse(null))) // Gives me Some(1) which I want

val one: Option[Int] = None
val two: Option[Int] = None

Option(one.getOrElse(two.getOrElse(null))) // Gives me None which I want

val one = Some(1)
val two = Some(2)

Option(one.getOrElse(two.getOrElse(null))) // Gives me Some(1) when I want an exception
```

I briefly looked into the Either type but it seems like it is for "Representing a value of one of two possible types".  Am I missing some data structure or Monad?  Essentially I want a explicit (and error throwing if both are valuable) get either one if it avaiable or get None

Comment: why don't you write a function for this, with pattern matching ?

Comment: @gzou I had considered that... I'm just checking if I'm missing something pre built

Comment: You can wrap them in a collection: `List(Option(1), Option(2)).forall(_.isDefined)` if it returns true all your options are defined and you can throw an exception.

Comment: @EndeNeu I answered with something similar.  Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: never ever ever use null. the whole point of option is to avoid null because it's safer, having an option return null if None defeats the entire purpose of the type

Comment: This sounds like `Option[Either[A, A]]`, and not `(Option[A], Option[A])`. "Make illegal states unrepresentable". Then what you want is `.map(_.merge)`.

Comment: (which is isomorphic to `Option[(Bool, A)]`, so `.map(_._2)`)

Comment: Note that throwing an Exception is not idiomatic from a Functional Programming point of view - http://stackoverflow.com/a/23184020/409976.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know any pre built to do that, so here is a function:

```
def xor[T](x: Option[T], y: Option[T]): Option[T] = (x, y) match {
    case (Some(_), None) => x
    case (None, Some(_)) => y
    case (None, None) => None
    case _ => throw new Exception()
}
```

Comment: the built-in function is called "orElse", only difference is that if you input `Some(2) orElse Some(8)` it'll return `Some(2)`

Answer (score 4):

Here's my version of the function

```
val options = Seq(one, two).flatten
if (options.size > 1) throw new Exception("two options were provided")
options.headOption
```

Comment: Seems unnecessarily obscure. Check for both the obvious way (direct translation of your spec `!(one.ifDefined && two.isDefined)` then `one orElse b`

Comment: There's a recent Q about checking a form of many options, where this scales.

Comment: @som-snytt got a link?

Answer (score 4):

```
def xor[T](a: Option[T], b: Option[T]) = 
    a orElse b ensuring (_ => a zip b isEmpty)
```

Comment: I like it, but improved: `(one orElse two) ensuring (_ => (one, two).zipped.isEmpty)`

Comment: At first I thought zipped might help, but it just makes the Lists and isEmpty uses Tuple2Zipped.foreach to iterate an element.

Comment: yeah...same old if-else much faster, but english-like code is more readable, and both fine i think

Answer (score 3):

I would probably go old school if-else for the simple case.

```
scala> implicit class optxor[A](val opt: Option[A]) extends AnyVal {
     | def xor(other: Option[A]) = if (opt.isEmpty) other else if (other.isEmpty) opt else ??? }
defined class optxor

scala> one xor two
res18: Option[Int] = Some(2)

scala> two xor three
scala.NotImplementedError: an implementation is missing
  at scala.Predef$.$qmark$qmark$qmark(Predef.scala:225)
  at optxor$.xor$extension(<console>:8)
  ... 33 elided
```

Comment: +1. Sometimes there's nothing wrong with `if ... then ... else ...`

Answer (score 1):

I would have approached this using a pattern matching function like gzou answered, but here's a one liner:

```
one.map{x => two.foreach(y => throw new Exception("both defined")); x}.orElse(two)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can combine the 2 `Option`s as an `Iterable` with `Option`'s [`++`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html#++[B%3E:A,That](that:scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[B])(implicitbf:scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Repr,B,That]):That) operator, and thus pattern match on iterables instead of tuple of options:

```
optionA ++ optionB match {
  case Seq(x, y) => throw new Exception
  case x => x.headOption
}
// None and None       => None
// Some(5) and None    => Some(5)
// None and Some(5)    => Some(5)
// Some(5) and Some(3) => Exception
```

Note `headOption` which nicely handles both the list with 1 element and the empty list.

Answer (score 0):

Or,

```
scala> val one: Option[Int] = None
one: Option[Int] = None

scala> val two = Option(2)
two: Option[Int] = Some(2)

scala> val three = Option(3)
three: Option[Int] = Some(3)

scala> (for (_ <- one; _ <- two) yield ???) orElse one orElse two
res0: Option[Int] = Some(2)

scala> (for (_ <- three; _ <- two) yield ???) orElse three orElse two
scala.NotImplementedError: an implementation is missing
  at scala.Predef$.$qmark$qmark$qmark(Predef.scala:225)
  at $anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(<console>:10)
  at $anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(<console>:10)
  at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
  at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:10)
  at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:10)
  at scala.Option.flatMap(Option.scala:170)
  ... 33 elided
```

desugaring to

```
scala> one flatMap (_ => two) map (_ => ???) orElse one orElse two
res3: Option[Int] = Some(2)
```

but idiomatically it's hard to imagine doing either of these.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
import scala.util.Try

object XorOption {

  def xorOptions[T](one: Option[T], two: Option[T]): Try[Option[T]] = {
    Try {
      for (x <- one; y <- two) throw new RuntimeException
      one.orElse(two)
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val testData = List(
      (None, None),
      (None, Some(2)),
      (Some(1), None),
      (Some(1), Some(2)))

    for (t <- testData) {
      println(t + " => " + xorOptions(t._1, t._2))
    }

  }

}
```

Output:

```
(None,None) => Success(None)
(None,Some(2)) => Success(Some(2))
(Some(1),None) => Success(Some(1))
(Some(1),Some(2)) => Failure(java.lang.RuntimeException)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List(Some(1), Some(2)).flatten match {
   case x :: Nil => Some(x)
   case Nil => None
   case _ => throw new Exception
}
```