# Scala Sequence of Int

Tags: scala, int, range, sequence

I have something like this:

```
    case class FunctionsTest(lowerBound: Int = 1,
                                upperBound: Int = 1000,
                                factor: Int = 2) {
  require(lowerBound < upperBound)

  /**
    * implement a sequence of ints, which start with lowerBound and end with
    * upperbound.
    *
    * for all elements following should be true:
    *
    * xs(i) < xs(i+1)
    * xs(i) + factor == xs(i + 1) (for i > 0 and i <= 1000)
    *
    */
  val xs: Seq[Int] = Seq.range(lowerBound,upperBound +1)
```

So I need a Sequence for this class which is making up these criteria.. I tried it with the

> Seq.range()

but it creates me the Sequence which is right for the first criteria but I don't know how to now apply the second criteria mentioned in the comment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `step` parameter of `Seq.range[T](start: T, end: T, step)` allows you to increase by factor.

```
scala> Seq.range(1,10,2)
res0: Seq[Int] = List(1, 3, 5, 7, 9)
```

This satisfies both criteria.

```
scala> res0.zip(res0.tail).forall(t => t._1 < t._2)
res4 Boolean = true
```

and

```
scala> res0(0) + 2 == res0(0 + 1)
res5: Boolean = true
```

Comment: There's certainly a better alternative than using `List#tail` - http://stackoverflow.com/a/23184020/409976.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but as @Kevin Meredith has mentioned it before, I would do it little bit different than zipping it and then checking the values with the forall operation. Anyway thank you for your solution!

Answer (score 4):

More generally, you can generate a sequence using an arbitrary function using `iterate`:

```
Seq.iterate(1,1000)(_ + 2)
```

For your case, the arbitrary function amounts to "a = a + 2", which gets applied over and over to the start value: 1, 1+2, (1+2)+2, ...

Answer (score 1):

You can create it with a simple [`Range`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Range).

inclusive : `(lowerBound to UpperBoud)`

exclusive : `(lowerBound until UpperBound)`

If you want a lazy evaluator, sort of like the tape counter for waiting at the post office, you can use scala [`Stream`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream).  They are very memory efficient because they only store the head of the Range, and lazily evaluate the tail only when needed.  Their map, filter, reduce, ... functions are also lazy.

```
scala.collection.immutable.Stream.range(lowerBound, upperBound)
```

Comment: Yeah that would be a great idea using a Stream, thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 1):

range method allows you to set step parameter

```
Seq.range(lower, upper, factor)
```

Comment: yeah this would create a list - in my case - like: Seq(1,3,5,7) and so on but this wouldn't match my criteria.