# Filter the list based on tuple element

Tags: scala

I have a List[(Int,Int)].

Ex.

```
val a = List((1,2),(2,3),(1,4),(2,4),(5,6),(4,5),(1,8))
```

I want to filter this list so that if several tuples have the same first element (same value in `_1`) then only the first tuple is kept.

So here the expected answer is :

```
val ans=List((1,2),(2,3),(5,6),(4,5))
```

As the first element of `(1,2)` is `1` and the same holds for `(1,4)`and `(1,8)`, we only keep the first occurrence (`(1,2)`) and ignore the others (`(1,4)`and `(1,8)`).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This preserves order and guarantees only the first is kept when duplicates are found, but it's not a terribly efficient algorithm.  Probably not a good idea for long lists.

```
scala> val a= List((1,2),(2,3),(1,4),(2,4),(5,6),(4,5),(1,8))
a: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,2), (2,3), (1,4), (2,4), (5,6), (4,5), (1,8))

scala> a.filter(x => a.filter(_._1 == x._1).head == x)
res22: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,2), (2,3), (5,6), (4,5))
```

Comment: Thanks @jwvh .. Its perfect solution for this question.

Comment: `head` is unsafe and should never be used - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23183935/foldl-implementation-with-runtime-errors.

Comment: @KevinMeredith, in this case, `head` _is_ safe. The inner `filter` will always return at least one element.

Comment: `head is what is known as a partial function: there are certain inputs for which head will crash.` - http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/lectures/03-rec-poly.html

Comment: @Kevin Meredith: What you are missing is that the lists are guaranteed to be non empty here, by the very definition of `groupBy`. So yes indeed it is by construction safe to call `head` here (if it ever fails at runtime, we've got a bug in `groupBy` which must be fixed).

Comment: Please see Tony Morris's tweet - https://twitter.com/dibblego/status/664964854126546944?s=09

Comment: @KevinMeredith, yep read it. Still missing the point. In this case, head _is_ safe. Whether it's a good idea to to use it in other contexts is a different question, but I don't think it was helpful just to make a blanket statement about it without considering the context. The "certain inputs" that make it crash cannot happen here.

Answer (score 7):

```
a.groupBy(_._1).values.collect{case x::xs=>x}
```

Edit, as suggested by @Régis Jean-Gilles,

```
a.groupBy(_._1).values.map(_.head)
```

Edit, to preserve the order

```
a.foldLeft(Map.empty[Int,(Int,Int)].empty){
    case (r,(x,y))=> if(r.contains(x)) r else r+(x->(x,y))
}.values
```

Comment: This solution does not preserve order. I don't know if that is important for you though.

Comment: `a.groupBy(_._1).values.map(_.head)` would work too (here `head` is guranteed to be safe given that each list returned by `groupBy` has necessarily at least one element). Though by using `groupBy`you lose the order. That is, not only the tuples might be in an incorrect order in the end, but I'm not even sure that `groupBy` is guaranteed to keep the eleemnts in order inside each list (in which case you're not even guaranteed to keep the **first** matching tuple, but only **one** matching tuple)

Comment: Order is not important for me.. But if I need in order than is there any solution?
And Yes `groupBy` keep elements inside the list in order.

Comment: @Regis Jean-Gilles, from the source of groupBy, it looks safe. But, map and using head does seem the right way.

Comment: When I talked about guarantee, I mean it as a contract.  No doubt that the order within each list is preserved by the current implementation, but isn'it simply an implementation detail that could change in futute versions?

Answer (score 4):

`ListMap` lets us both eliminate duplicate keys and preserve order:

```
scala> val a= List((1,2),(2,3),(1,4),(2,4),(5,6),(4,5),(1,8))
a: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,2), (2,3), (1,4), (2,4), (5,6), (4,5), (1,8))

scala> collection.immutable.ListMap(a.reverse: _*).toList.reverse
res0: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,2), (2,3), (5,6), (4,5))
```

Comment: Cool, I didn't know about ListMap.

Comment: Does ListMap's contract (rather than the current implementation) guarantee order?

Comment: Yes, that's the whole idea of ListMap. It will be documented as such in Scala 2.11.8: https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/4788. I see the ListMap doc doesn't specify how duplicate keys are handled; I believe we would accept a pull request that added that to the doc, too.

Comment: Ah, cool (/me adds ListMap to his box of tricks). Interesting to see my previous comments referred to :)

Answer (score 2):

```
scala> val a = List((1,2),(2,3),(1,4),(2,4),(5,6),(4,5),(1,8))
a: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,2), (2,3), (1,4), (2,4), (5,6), (4,5), (1,8))
scala> a.reverse.toMap.toList
res7: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,2), (4,5), (5,6), (2,3))
```

Doesn't preserve the order, but quite concise.

Comment: see my answer for an order-preserving version

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is almost `.distinct`, with a different test for "duplicate". Let's see how the standard library does `.distinct`:

```
 /** Builds a new $coll from this $coll without any duplicate elements.
   *  $willNotTerminateInf
   *
   *  @return  A new $coll which contains the first occurrence of every element of this $coll.
   */
  def distinct: Repr = {
    val b = newBuilder
    val seen = mutable.HashSet[A]()
    for (x <- this) {
      if (!seen(x)) {
        b += x
        seen += x
      }
    }
    b.result()
  }
```

We can do something a little less generic, but along the same lines:

```
  import scala.collection.mutable.{ListBuffer, HashSet}

  def distinctByFirst[A,B](xs:List[(A, B)]) = {
    val b = new ListBuffer[(A,B)]
    val seen = HashSet[A]()
    for (x <- xs) {
      if (!seen(x._1)) {
        b += x
        seen += x._1
      }
    }
    b.result()
  }

  distinctByFirst(a)
  //> res0: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,2), (2,3), (5,6), (4,5))
```