# How to find unique elements from list of tuples based on some elements using scala?

Tags: scala

I have following list

```
val a = List(("name1","add1","city1",10),("name1","add1","city1",10),

("name2","add2","city2",10),("name2","add2","city2",20),("name3","add3","city3",20))
```

I want distinct element from above list based on first three values of tuple. Fourth value should not be consider while finding distinct elements from list.

I want following output:

```
val output = List(("name1","add1","city1",10),("name2","add2","city2",10),

("name3","add3","city3",20))
```

Is it possible to get above output?

**As per my knowledge, `distinct` works if whole tuple/value is duplicated.  I tried out with `distinct` like following**:

```
val b = List(("name1","add1","city1",10),("name1","add1","city1",10),("name2","add2","city2",10),
("name2","add2","city2",20),("name3","add3","city3",20)).distinct
```

but it gives output as -

```
List(("name1","add1","city1",10),("name2","add2","city2",10),
("name2","add2","city2",20),("name3","add3","city3",20))
```

**Any alternate approach will also appreciated.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter the list based on tuple element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666965/filter-the-list-based-on-tuple-element)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `groupBy` like this

```
a.groupBy( v => (v._1,v._2,v._3)).keys.toList
```

This constructs a `Map` where each key is by definition a unique triplet as required in the lambda function above.

Should it include also the last element in the tuple, fetch the first element for each key, like this

```
a.groupBy( v => (v._1,v._2,v._3)).mapValues(_.head)
```

Answer (score 5):

If the order of the output list isn't important (i.e. you are happy to get `List(("name3","add3","city3",20),("name1","add1","city1",10),("name2","add2","city2",10))`), the following works as specified:

```
a.groupBy(v => (v._1,v._2,v._3)).values.map(_.head).toList
```

(Due to Scala collections design, you'll see the order kept for output lists up to 4 elements, but above that size `HashMap` will be used.) If you do need to keep the order, you can do something like (generalizing a bit)

```
def distinctBy[A, B](xs: Seq[A], f: A => B) = {
  val seen = LinkedHashMap.empty[B, A]
  xs.foreach { x =>
    val key = f(x)
    if (!seen.contains(key)) { seen.update(key, x) }
  }
  seen.values.toList
}

distinctBy(a, v => (v._1, v._2, v._3))
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try

```
a.map{case x@(name, add, city, _) => (name,add,city) -> x}.toMap.values.toList
```

Answer (score 2):

To make sure you have the first one in list kept,

```
  type String3 = (String, String, String)
  type String3Int = (String, String, String, Int)
  a.foldLeft(collection.immutable.ListMap.empty[String3, String3Int]) {
    case (a, b) => if (a.contains((b._1, b._2, b._3))) {
      a
    } else a + ((b._1, b._2, b._3) -> b)
  }.values.toList
```

Comment: This preserves early elements that later ones when they conflict. This is what I want. Thanks for the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

On simple solution would be to convert the List to a Set. Sets don't contain duplicates: [check the documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/sets.html).

```
 val setOfTuples = a.toSet
 println(setOfTuples)
```

Output: `Set((1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,1))`