# String of Key-Value Pairs to Map

Tags: scala

I have strings of the following pattern. `"\key1\value1\key2\value2\..."`

How can these be turned into a `Map("key1" -> "value1", "key2" -> "value2")` elegantly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your example is an invalid string literal as \ is the escape character, so I assume you wanted a -character before each value and key, even before the first one.

If that's the case you can do what you want like this:

```
val s = """\key1\value1\key2\value2"""
s.split('\\').toList.tail.grouped(2).map{case List(a,b) => a -> b}.toMap
```

Consult the API documentation on List to find what the Operations are doing.

Comment: Replace current `s` with `val s = """\key1\value1\key2\value2\WHOOPS"""`, then you'll get an exception: `s.split('\\').toList.tail.grouped(2).map{case List(a,b) => a -> b}.toMap
scala.MatchError: List(WHOOPS) (of class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon)`. Also, `List#tail` is a partial function that should be [avoided](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23184020/409976).

Comment: Well, there is always a point where you have to program against some invariant. If one wants to do error handling in this case, there are different ways to go about it. But this is a simple answer for an obvious beginner. If he gets that, we can talk about how to turn this in a total function.